# Перезагрузка страницы с модального окна

Tags: php, javascript

Всем здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос: есть страница, которая при ссылке открывает модальное окно. В этом модальном окне открывается другая страница (другой *url*) c множеством различных ссылок с разными *id*. Мне нужно чтобы при клике на эту ссылку родительская страница переходила на другой *url* (например, к ней добавлялось "`?id=$id`").

Еще раз обращаю внимание, что файлы родительского и модального окна разные (к примеру родительское `www.mysite.ru/1.php`, а в модальном окне открывается `www.mysite.ru/2.php`)

Всем заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, в браузерах есть ограничение безопасности, которые не позволяют из дочернего окна (или фрейма) управлять родительским или исполнять какой то код.

Answer (score 0):

Так попробуйте

```
window.opener.document.location.href = новый url;
```

up

Вот решение через контроль из родительского окна. 
Файл test1.php запускаем первоначально. Из него будет открыто модальное окно с файлом test2.php. Функция openwin() будет контролировать содержимое скрытого input в модальном окне. Если скрытый input примет значение отличное от пустого, это значение будет вставлено в адресную строку основного окна и произойдет переход по данному адресу.

```
<script>
var w;
function openwin()
{
  w = window.open('test2.php');
    setTimeout('wtimer();', 100);
}

function wtimer()
{
    var url = w.document.getElementById('heddenURL').value;
    if (!!url)
    {
      window.location.href = url;
    }
    else
    {
      setTimeout('wtimer();', 100);
    }
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="openwin(); return false;" value="Launch" />
```

Файл test2.php

```
<input type="hidden" id="heddenURL" name="heddenURL" value="">
New url <input type="text" name="newURL" onchange="document.getElementById('heddenURL').value = this.value; return false;">
```

Comment: к сожалению, это не работает на Google Chrome. Или я что-то не так делаю может?

Comment: А так? window.opener.location.href = новый url;

Comment: Внес исправление в соответствии с ответом @Alexey Lemesh.